# Sailsjs - How to use mySQL

Tags: mysql, sails.js

How to use mysql with Sails ? Also, if I change the database to a mySQL one, do I lose all my current model data ?

I spent some time looking for tutorials and demos but haven't found any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use mySQL with sails, you will have to:

- Define an adapter in **config/adapters**

Example adapters file:

```
    module.exports.adapters = {
            'default': 'disk', 
            disk: {
                    module: 'sails-disk'
            },
            'mysql-adapter': {
                    module: 'sails-mysql',
                    host: 'HOST',
                    user: 'USER',
                    password: 'PASSWORD',
                    database: 'DATABASE'
            }
    };
```

- Make any model use the new mysql adapter **(ex. api/models/Contact.js)**

  ```
  module.exports = {
      tableName: 'contacts',
      adapter: 'mysql-adapter',
      migrate: 'safe',
      attributes: { ... }
  }
  ```

Then it should work.

Comment: I had to rename mysql-adapter to mysqlAdapter to get it working. (Sails JS v0.9.16).