# sails-mysql: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

When trying to use sails-mysql I get an `ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected` exception.
Even though I followed all the instructions I was able to find as closely as possible. I also looked into related issues:

- [Sailsjs - How to use mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521525/sailsjs-how-to-use-mysql)
- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/632
- http://dustinbolton.com/error-er_no_db_error-no-database-selected/

Nothing seemed to help so far.

**This is what I am doing:**

I started out with a fresh project:

```
sails new sql-test
cd sql-test
```

Installed sails-mysql

```
sudo npm install sails-mysql
```

I changed the config:

```
// config/adapters.js

module.exports.adapters = {
  'default': 'mysql',
  mysql: {
    module   : 'sails-mysql',
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 3306,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'superSecret',
    database : 'testDB'
  }
};
```

Created a Model:

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
      name: 'string'
  }
};
```

And when I try to run it from the project's root:

```
sails lift
```

I get the following:

```
Logic error in mySQL ORM.
{ [Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected] code: 'ER_NO_DB_ERROR', index: 0 }
error: Hook failed to load: orm (Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected)
error: Error encountered while loading Sails core!
error: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:32:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:82:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
    at Parser.write (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
    --------------------
    at Query.Sequence (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
    at new Query (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:12:12)
    at Function.Connection.createQuery (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:48:10)
    at Connection.query (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:100:26)
    at __DESCRIBE__ (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:121:20)
    at afterwards (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:571:7)
    at Handshake._callback (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:549:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:66:24)
    at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
    at Parser.write (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/tster/Documents/sandbox/sql-test/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

---

### Additional Information:

- **sails** v0.9.13
- **sails-mysql** (v0.9.9)
- **mysql** v14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
- I can connect the the database via command line.
- I am able to connect and query the Database when using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

Could anybody give me some advice? Am I missing something? Anything else I should check out?

Comment: What's the version of Sails.js and `sails-mysql`?

Comment: sorry, for the sake of completeness:
sails (v0.9.13) and 
sails-mysql (v0.9.9)

Comment: It looks like this is happening as something tries to access the database while Sails is lifting.  I tried with a new Sails v0.9 app and wasn't able to reproduce.  Do you happen to have a web page open that might be trying to connect via Sockets as Sails is starting up, or some other bootstrap code that might be hitting the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just hit this same problem. In order to get it to work, I had to add the adapter configuration information to my model, e.g. /api/models/User.js:

```
module.exports = {

     adapter: 'mysql',

      config: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'user',
        port:'3306',
        // Psst.. You can put your password in config/local.js instead
        // so you don't inadvertently push it up if you're using version control
        password: 'secret', 
        database: 'sailstest'
      },

    attributes: {
    firstName: 'STRING'
    }

};
```

See the docs:

http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

I also had to add /api/controllers/UserController.js manually, as the generate function did not add it on this app, although it did add it on the previous test app I made.

UPDATE:

Install the Sails.js beta to get better functionality.

```
npm install sails@beta -g
```

Not only does the config actually work as expected (under config/connections.js), the ORM features support associations, which are not supported in the 0.9 release.

Comment: wow, that actually worked. thank you!
Even though as far as I understood the documentation, I only need to explicitly specify the adapter inside a model if I want to override the global configuration (im my case default: 'mysql') in config/adapters.js? But for some reasons my global default settings ignored for some reason.

Comment: I just installed the Sails.js beta and have found it to be far better than the current release. Do this: npm install sails@beta -g.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has an answer, but it's more of a workaround.  This is what fixed the same issue for me.

Changing the default adapters.js file mysql adapter object from `myLocalMySQLDatabase` to simply `mysql` seemed to fix it for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may get this error when the `.env` file is not in the same directory.

You can check what the error is with the following code:

```
const result = require('dotenv').config();
if (result.error) {
  console.log(result.error)
}
console.log(result.parsed)
```

Comment: This helped so much! Thanks. Added somebody new to the project. They had to setup a .env file because it isn't in the repository. They were getting the following error: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected. We couldn't figure it out. I added the code you provided to our index.js and it displayed the config info in the .env file. When they added it, they got an error that the file didn't exist. Turns out they added the file as an "env", not a ".env".

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You must take care about data type.

if you have module like this

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
      name: 'string'
  }
};
```

In database under modal name table field name must be varchar.

My database field is set to text and I getting this error , when change it to varchar everything work.