# sails-mysql No database Selected

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've googled this quite a bit, and looked at other solutions on stack overflow but have found nothing that fixes my issue.  When defining a model to use mysql instead of disk I get the following error

```
verbose: Registering model `users` in Waterline (ORM) with definition :: 
 { identity: 'users',
  tableName: 'users',
  connections: 
       [ { pool: true,
       connectionLimit: 10,
       waitForConnections: true,
       adapter: 'sails-mysql' } ],
  config: 
   { host: 'localhost',
     port: 3306,
     user: 'root',
     password: 'password',
     database: 'sailsapp' },
  attributes: { name: 'string', email: 'string', phone: 'string' },
  globalId: 'users',
  introduce: [Function: bound],
  obituary: [Function: bound],
  publish: [Function: bound],
  pluralize: [Function],
  room: [Function: bound],
  classRoom: [Function],
  subscribers: [Function],
  publishCreate: [Function: bound],
  publishUpdate: [Function: bound],
  publishDestroy: [Function: bound],
  subscribe: [Function: bound],
  unsubscribe: [Function: bound],
  adapter: [ 'adhoc_adapter_0' ] } 

Logic error in mySQL ORM.
{ [Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected] code: 'ER_NO_DB_ERROR', index: 0 }
error: Hook failed to load: orm (Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected)
verbose: Hooks loaded!
error: Error encountered while loading Sails core!
error: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
at Query.Sequence._packetToError     (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-    mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:32:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:82:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
at Parser.write (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
--------------------
at Query.Sequence (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
at new Query (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:12:12)
at Function.Connection.createQuery (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:48:10)
at Connection.query (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:100:26)
at __DESCRIBE__ (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:121:20)
at afterwards (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:571:7)
at Handshake._callback (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:37:9)
at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:66:24)
at Handshake.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:75:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:172:24)
at Parser.write (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/rich/PhpstormProjects/sailsjs/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
at Socket.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
```

I have read in other places that there is a known error with the new version of sails.js (0.9.16) where the adapter and config have to be specified for each model.  I have done that as you can see from the error log, however the code for my model is below

```
module.exports = {
    adapter: 'mysql',
    config: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'sailsapp'
    },

    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        email: 'string',
        phone: 'string'
    }
};
```

I'm still getting the same error.  Here is the package.json file for my app

```
{
    "name": "sailsjs",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "a Sails application",
    "dependencies": {
        "sails": "0.9.16",
        "grunt": "0.4.1",
        "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
        "ejs": "0.8.4",
        "optimist": "0.3.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "debug": "node debug app.js"
    },
    "main": "app.js",
    "repository": "",
    "author": "",
    "license": ""
}
```

and the package.json file for my version of sails-mysql

```
{
  "name": "sails-mysql",
  "version": "0.9.9",
  "description": "MySQL adapter for Sails.js",
  "main": "lib/adapter.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "make test"
  }, ...
```

Are there any suggestions about how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Duplicate question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548976/sails-mysql-er-no-db-error-no-database-selected

Comment: As explained in my question this answer did not work for me

I just hit this same problem. In order to get it to work, I had to add the adapter configuration information to my model, e.g. /api/models/User.js:

I have already done this, I have documented that fact in my question

Comment: Using a new app in v0.9.16, I can't replicate this.  It looks like the error is happening on lift after getting a socket event; do you have a web page open that may be trying to re-connect with your server and write data as Sails is lifting?

Comment: I'll try looking into this in the morning.  I did add some logic to the on socket connect so this may be causing the issue.  I'll let you know what I come up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the default adapters.js file mysql adapter object from `myLocalMySQLDatabase` to simply `mysql` seemed to fix it.  Don't know why they changed the name of the mysql adapter object but we're good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

In v0.10, connection name can be defined on **models.js** which was configured on **connections.js**

**models.js**

```
 connection: 'someMysqlServer'
```

**connections.js**

```
 someMysqlServer: {
    adapter : 'sails-mysql',
    host    : 'localhost',
    user    : '',
    password: '', 
    database: ''
  }
```